# Declaration or statement expected when exporting

Tags: reactjs, typescript, redux

I'm exporting all my reducers from this `index.js` like this:

```
export checking from 'reducers/Checking';
export saving from 'reducers/Saving';
export overdraft from 'reducers/Overdraft';
..........
```

I started getting the following error on every line above ^, when I try to integrate Typescript into my project:

```
 Declaration or statement expected
```

I have `stage-0` in my presets to support that kind of syntax, but still getting that error.

**tsconfig.json**

Could anybody direct me to how towards how get rid of that error?

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "lib": [
      "dom",
      "dom.iterable",
      "esnext"
    ],
    "allowJs": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "strict": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "module": "es2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "noEmit": true,
    "jsx": "react"
  },
  "include": [
    "src"
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the form of export you're using doesn't exist. You can find a list of the forms in the spec [here](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#table-42), but there isn't an `export x from "y"` form.

It looks to me like you're trying to re-export the **default export** of each of those modules as a named export. That is, you have `export default ...` in `reducers/Checking.ts` (for example) and want to re-export that from `index.ts` as `checking`. If so, you have to use the named form and the identifier `default` explicitly:

```js
// Re-exports the default export of each module
export { default as checking } from 'reducers/Checking';
export { default as saving } from 'reducers/Saving';
export { default as overdraft } from 'reducers/Overdraft';
```

But if you have named exports like `export const checking ...` in `reducers/Checking.ts` (for example) and you're trying to re-export **all** of its **named exports** from `index.ts`, you'd do it like this:

```js
// Re-exports all named exports from each module:
export * from 'reducers/Checking';
export * from 'reducers/Saving';
export * from 'reducers/Overdraft';
```

Or if you were trying to export just a **single named export**, you'd do it like this:

```js
// Re-exports a named export from each module:
export { checking } from 'reducers/Checking';
export { saving } from 'reducers/Saving';
export { overdraft } from 'reducers/Overdraft';
```

Finally, if you were trying to export a **module namespace object** for each of those modules (an object with a property for each of the module's exports), you'd do it like this:

```js
// Re-exports a named export from each module:
export * as checking from 'reducers/Checking';
export * as saving from 'reducers/Saving';
export * as overdraft from 'reducers/Overdraft';
```

All of the above assume `reducers` is in `node_modules`. If it's your own directory instead, you need `./` at the beginning of those module specifiers (`from './reducers/Checking'` instead of `from 'reducers/Checking'`).

---

Separately: To use JavaScript module syntax (often called ESM for **E**CMA**S**cript **M**odules), you need tell TypeScript that's what you're doing. There are a couple of ways to do that:

1. If you have `"target": "ES6"` or higher, TypeScript will assume you're using JavaScript modules (instead of CommonJS etc.)
2. You can use `"module": "ES2015"` to explicitly opt into JavaScript modules.

Comment: i'm still getting the same thing no matter what i do. I posted my tsconfig.json in any case in my question

Comment: @Julie - Sorry, I should have looked more closely at the actual export statements (I assumed it was a problem turning ESM on, my bad). `export x from "y"` isn't a defined form of export. I've updated the answer with a list of the re-exporting forms you'd use depending on what exactly is it from the reducers you want to export. Sorry again for misunderstanding the question.

Comment: FWIW, I go into detail on `import`/`export` and just generally how ESM works in Chapter 13 of my new book *JavaScript: The New Toys*. If you're interested, the details are in my profile.

Answer (score 1):

```
export * from 'reducers/Checking';
export * from 'reducers/Saving';
export * from 'reducers/Overdraft';
```

You have to try this.

Comment: If they're doing a roll-up module, yes. To me it looks like they're trying to re-export the default export, but they might well be trying to do this (re-export all named exports) instead -- nice one.